# How can I measure the difference/similarity between two vectors?

Tags: vector-spaces

How can I measure the difference/similarity of two vectors?

That is...Let us suppose that I have two vectors in R^3: v1 = {1,8,3} v2 = {2,5,10} Let us consider that v1 and v2 are representing directions.

I would like to measure how much v1 and v2 are pointing to the same direction.

Comment: Look up the dot product.

Comment: In the sapiens vector space, one can use the Myers-Brigg personality test.

Comment: If the main concern is the similarity of the direction of the vectors I would normalise before taking the inner-product, so take $\frac{\langle v_{1},v_{2}\rangle}{\|v_{1}\|\|v_{2}\|}=\cos(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the two vectors.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I forgot to mention that I would like to find a measure tht is able to capture the fact that an angle of 180 degrees would produce the maximum difference.

I have found the cosine similarity, but it seems that this measure assumes that maximaly different vectors have 90 degress between them.

Comment: $\langle v_1,v_2\rangle \|v_1\times v_2\|$ will be proportional to $\sin2\theta$. Normalize first, as @FlorisClaassens suggests.

Comment: @Zaratruta The maximal difference is actually 180 degrees. The biggest difference in direction occurs if $v_{1}=-v_{2}$ which gives $\frac{\langle v_{1},v_{2}\rangle}{\|v_{1}\|\|v_{2}\|}=-1=\cos(\theta)$ which only occurs for $\theta=180^{\circ}$.